# Asking how to sort in a csv being repeated

Tags: sorting, csv, python-3.x

I have a quiz with results that are sorted into a .csv file, after the questions are answered it asks the user if the results should be sorted alphabetically or by highest to lowest. This question is then repeated no matter the answer entered, however if highest to lowest is entered a few times after alphabetically it works.

```
print ("Would you like to see the results alphabetically or by highest to    lowest?")
alpha = input()
while alpha != "alphabetically":
  alpha = str(input ("Would you like to see the results alphabetically or by   highest to lowest? "))
  break
while alpha != "highest to lowest":
  alpha = str(input ("Would you like to see the results alphabetically or by highest to lowest? "))
  break


def updatefile(file,sortby,Classnumber): #this shortens the code by about 3 lines per file update 
 if Class == Classnumber:
    with open(file,'a') as f:
        file_writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ',', lineterminator='\n')
        file_writer.writerow((name,score))
        sortcsv(file,sortby)

if alpha == "alphabetically": 
   updatefile('Class 1 Results.csv',0,"1")  #saves space using shortened code, makes the code use alphabetical sorting
   updatefile('Class 2 Results.csv',0,"2")
   updatefile('Class 3 Results.csv',0,"3")

elif alpha == "highest to lowest":
   updatefile('Class 1 Results.csv',1,"1")  #makes the code use highest to lowest sorting
   updatefile('Class 2 Results.csv',1,"2")
   updatefile('Class 3 Results.csv',1,"3")
```

Comment: I've added a break after alpha != alphabetically and what follows it, now it asks the question twice and does whatever you tell it to the second time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's step through that input block and see what's going on.

```
print ("Would you like to see the results alphabetically or by highest to lowest?")
alpha = input()
```

Ok so far, but it's puzzling why you `print`ed the prompt this time, and put it in the `input()` statement the rest.

```
while alpha != "alphabetically":
    alpha = str(input ("Would you like to see the results alphabetically or by highest to lowest? "))
```

Now if the user didn't enter "alphabetically" at the first prompt, they will be prompted over and over until they do. That's probably not what you're going for. (Also, you don't need `str()` around `input()`.)

```
while alpha != "highest to lowest":
    highesttolowest = str(input ("Would you like to see the results alphabetically or by highest to lowest? "))
    break
```

Now that your user finally entered "alphabetically", you prompt them again (since "alphabetically" != "highest to lowest"). Two major problems here, though. First, the unconditional `break` renders the `while` loop pointless, as it will always exit after one loop. Second, you're assigning the input to a new variable `highesttolowest`, but later on you're still testing against `alpha`, so the results of this prompt won't ever be checked.

The simpest way to do what you seem to want to be doing is to use membership testing to check for both conditions at the same time. Replace that whole block with:

```
alpha = ''
while alpha not in ("alphabetically", "highest to lowest"):
    alpha = input("Would you like to see the results alphabetically or by highest to lowest? ")
```